# Update array of numbers so they are after each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of numbers that a user can add and remove from a page. I need to arrange the numbers in the array so they are always after each other when a number is added/removed

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

5 is removed from the array of how do I fix so the numbers are after each other e.g below

numbers need to be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

or if 2 is removed

```
numbers need to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Is there a way to fix this with lodash or es6?

Comment: how can you remove a number and the number stays?

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I think what they're saying is, they remove `5` leaving them with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]` and then want to adjust the subsequent values so they end up with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` (no `8`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Removing the number from Array, you can iterate over it using for loop, and assign that index number to that position in array.

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
numbers.splice(1, 1)     //2 was removed
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  numbers[i] = i+1;
}
```

Comment: const numbers = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
numbers.splice(1, 1)     //2 was removed
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  numbers[i] = i+1;
}

What should change in case I need to preserve duplicates like above?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

After you've removed the number, loop through the array and set the number to the index of the array.

Using `.forEach()`

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const removed = array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  array.forEach((_, i) => array[i] = i);

  console.log(`Removed: `, removed[0]);
  console.log(`New Array`, array);
});
```

Using `.map()`

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const removed = array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  array = array.map((_, i) => i);

  console.log(`Removed: `, removed[0]);
  console.log(`New Array`, array);
});
```